# Counting Numbers And Sorting Them

Tags: php, echo, calculation

I have a question. I have created a small script which generates 37 random numbers between 0 and 36 but I want to expand it a little.

This is what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php  
for ($x = 1; $x <= 37; $x++) {
  echo(mt_rand(0,36) . "<br>");
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to show a horizontal row of number 0 to 36 and below that I want to show how many times a number show from the previous random generator code.

Can someone help me here?

Comment: i would save the results from the random generation in an array the use array_count_values() to get the count then a loop again for output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php

    $numberOfSpins = 10000;
    $numberArray = array();

    // Start table
    echo '<table>
          <tr>';

    // print out the table headers
    for ($x = 0; $x < 37; $x++) echo '<th style="font-weight:bold; color:#09f;">'.$x.'</th>';

    // Fill $numberArray with random numbers
    for($i=0; $i < $numberOfSpins; $i++) array_push($numberArray, mt_rand(0,36));

     echo '</tr>
           <tr>';       

    // Count value frequency using PHP function array_count_value()
    $resultArray = array_count_values($numberArray);

    // Start from 0 since you are generating numbers from 0 to 36
    for($i=0; $i < 37; $i++)
    {
        // array_count_values() returns an associative array (the key of
        // each array item is the value it was counting and the value is the 
        // occurrence count; [key]->value).
        if (isset($resultArray[$i])) echo '<td>'.$resultArray[$i].'</td>';
        else echo '<td>0</td>';
    }

   echo '</tr>
         </table>';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Ivan86,

This is going the right way. The reason I am creating the script is because I want to research roulette and it's relation to the chaose theory.

As you know roulette has 37 numbers going from 0 to 36. I have uploaded your script to xampp but I notice that it counts from 1 to 37. How can I adjust it to 0 to 36 and below show the count of the certain numbers spung?

And last but not least, what number do I need to change to spin a 100 time instead of 37?

Thanks for your help so far. ;)

Comment: I have edited my answer to let you perform an arbitrary amount of spins and adjusted output from 0-36. Sorry bout that that was typo from my side. Hope everything works well now. Oh, and Chaos theory truly is amazing. I'm amazed at how it works also.

Comment: You are simply amazing. I'm a member from a roulette forum for quite some time now and one of my forum friends over there has discovered something which is holding up for over 3 months now and we are researching if we can improve the system further, if you are interested and find it interesting I can introduce you over there.

Can you show me how I can add a chart below the table it so I can visualize the results shown inside the table?

Comment: Sure, why not, could be interesting. Yes, I could show you charts, that is no problem. Oh and if my original answer answered your question, mark it as the answer please.

Comment: Done. Do you have skype?

Comment: My Sype is ivan.jakovcevic you can add me, country is Croatia.

Comment: Hi. I have added you but can't seem to see if you are online.

Comment: I think you have added the wrong person, I don't see any request. [This](https://ibb.co/hn68Zm) is me on Skype.

Comment: Hey Ivan, Are you online on skype?

Comment: Hi Ivan, Can we meet online on skype tommorow?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array and save the result on it.

**Code**

You can use `array_count_values`

```
$random_numbers = array();
echo 'Random Numbers: ';
for ($x = 1; $x <= 37; $x++) {
    $random_numbers[] = mt_rand(0,36);
}
print_r(array_count_values($random_numbers));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [21] => 1
    [22] => 1
    [15] => 1
    [6] => 2
    [13] => 2
    [24] => 2
    [35] => 3
    [0] => 1
    [3] => 2
    [32] => 1
    [19] => 2
    [9] => 2
    [28] => 2
    [29] => 1
    [33] => 1
    [11] => 1
    [2] => 3
    [25] => 1
    [10] => 2
    [4] => 1
    [30] => 1
    [20] => 1
    [27] => 1
    [26] => 1
    [12] => 1
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a variable to store the values and then use [array_keys](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-keys.php) to display the column number and [arrays_values](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-values.php) to print the values. The latter is optional.

```
<?php

$numbers = [];

for($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) {
    $numbers[$x] = mt_rand(0,36);
}

echo implode("\t | \t", array_keys($numbers));
echo PHP_EOL;
echo implode("\t | \t", $numbers);
```